# Boost Tutorial: Function Code will not compile: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++, function, boost

I am trying to use some code written by someone else who has incorporated Boost functions in their code.  That is why I am using Boost functions in this stripped-down example.

Given that I am new to Boost and Boost functions, I was following the tutorial at:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html

under "Basic Usage".

I am getting the error: "error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments"

As you can see, I have tried a couple of forms, but still get the same error.

Any ideas?

TIA

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include  <time.h>


// 3. Standard library headers
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

//using namespace  std;

//  Boost Codes

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

#define   CASE1 0
#define   CASE2 1

/**********************************************************************************/
#if CASE1
struct getLogName  
{
  std::string  operator()(std::string& InputFileName) const { return InputFileName; };
};
#endif 


#if CASE2
std::string  getLogName (std::string& InputFileName)
{
  return (InputFileName);
}

#endif
/**********************************************************************************/
/* Main function, starting point for the program */
int main (int argc, char *argv[])

{
  path p = current_path();

  std::string   PathString = p.string ();
  std::string   FileName = PathString + "\\XML_LogFile.log";

#if CASE1 
  boost::function<std::string()>   f;
  f = getLogName ();
  std::cout << f (FileName);     //  C2064
#elif CASE2
  boost::function<std::string()>   f = getLogName;
  std::cout << f (FileName);     //  C2064
#endif

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: `boost::function<std::string()>` is a function object that takes **no parameters** and returns a `std::string`.  That doesn't seem to agree with the rest of your code.  The rest of your code implies that you actually wanted `boost::function<std::string(std::string&)>`.

Comment: And that was exactly the insight that I needed!  I changed the line to boost::function<std::string(std::string &)>   f = getLogName;  and it worked!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Drew Dormann had the answer.  The code in the main part is now:

```
#if CASE1 
  boost::function<std::string(std::string &)>   f;
  f = getLogName ();
  std::cout << f (FileName);     
#elif CASE2
  boost::function<std::string(std::string &)>   f = getLogName;
  std::cout << f (FileName);     
#endif
```

and that works!